# Include jQuery in intern test

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, intern

How can I test custom JavaScript app (including jQuery as a dependency)? I have tried jQuery as Node package with no success...

Do I need to define it somehow in the test suite dependencies? I tried this:

```
define([
    'intern!bdd',
    'intern/chai!expect',
    'node-jquery'
], ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re on the right track. If you are trying to load and test arbitrary JavaScript, you just do so like this:

```js
define([
  'intern!bdd',
  'intern/chai!expect',
  'libs/jquery.js',
  'app/foo.js',
  'app/bar.js'
], function (bdd, expect) {
  bdd.describe('my test', function () {
    bdd.it('should find foos on the page', function () {
      expect(jQuery('.foo')).to.have.length.of.at.least(2);
    });
  });

  // access other global variables here
});
```

Comment: Well, I get the message that `window is not defined at .../js/jquery.js:2:93372`. However, I have solved this by running the tests in the browser.

Comment: Is it possible to run Intern test (for browser JS app, using jQuery + Ember.js) in the command line?

Comment: Probably not. You can run any tests from the command line as long as they don't require DOM. If jQuery, Ember, or RandomAwesomeFramework expect a browser environment, a test that loads them won't work from the command line. Check out this [wiki page](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Tests) for more info on running tests.

Comment: This is an old thread, but Intern has added support for PhantomJS with Selenium, which means that indeed you can test Javascript that needs the DOM from the command line. [Check it out](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-with-PhantomJS)

Comment: i'm not able to load jquery - as i'm running test from command line giving me an error

 var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
                                                   ^
TypeError: process.cwd is not a function